# How to call a c# method when working with LINQ to NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq, nhibernate

How to call a c# method when working with LINQ to NHibernate?

The below code fails:

```
List<UriTemplate> result1 = (from uriTemplate in this.SessionFactory.Session.Query<UriTemplate>()
                             where Regex.Match(uri, uriTemplate.UriTemplateValue).Success
                             select uriTemplate).ToList();
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: "The below code fails"... how?  Is it the `Regex` call that fails?

Answer (score 5):

Not all methods are supported. Things like Contains and Substring might work. But you cannot expect that the underlying LINQ provider will be able to translate arbitrary C# methods to SQL. The underlying database might not even know what a regex is.

You will have to do the filtering on the client side, once you execute the query on the server:

```
List<UriTemplate> result1 = this
    .SessionFactory
    .Session
    .Query<UriTemplate>()
    .ToList()
    .Where(uriTemplate => Regex.Match(uri, uriTemplate.UriTemplateValue).Success)
    .ToList();
```

If your underlying database supports regex queries that will probably be done through some native function in which case you will need to invoke this [`native function`](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/querysql.html) if you want to do the filtering on the server.

Comment: but each time I'd have to load the whole database then :(

Comment: In this case you will need to use a native function: http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/querysql.html